# How to write this join query in cdbcriteria?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, yii

I've been stuck for three hours and I cannot find a solution, I want to show only the name of those packages which are in the `business_package` table in my dropdown.
My sql query which is working fine I do not know how to write in cdbcriteria, I tried to write in cdbcriteria, but I get error every time. Given below is my sql query.

```
select package.id
from package
join business_package on package.id = business_package.package_id
```

I want to use the results in given below drop down list.

```
$this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2',array(
  'name'=>'ReviewPackage[Package_id]',
  'data'=>CHtml::listData(Package::model()->findAll($criteria), 'id', 'package_name'), 
  //the whole available list of those package which are in business package table.
  'htmlOptions'=>array(
       'placeholder'=>' search Business name?',
    //'options'=>$options, //the selected values
   // 'multiple'=>'multiple',
    'style'=>'width:530px',
  ),
  ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder

Something like that should do it:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->alias = 'package';
$criteria->select = 'package.id';
$criteria->join='LEFT JOIN business_package ON business_package.package_id=package.id';
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken the Yii would apply an alias to your "primary" table, and that is "t", but for various reasons you can explicitly set the table alias. In this case just for readability of the query.